# How does one answer questions about G-Mail account for recovery?

Tags: google-account, email, account-recovery

Question originally posted provides specific details not answered by 9-year-old question to which it redirects without notice. Having sensibly jumped right to the answers, I only noticed it wasn't *my question* after several minutes of going thru that questions irrelevant answers, and tried to first post a comment, then answer to that effect. Someone else's question/problem doesn't answer *my* question/problem. Please don't redirect it and re-post/bump to top/today.

> I haven't used G-Mail in a long time, but want to save it from
> deletion on June 1. I forgot my password for a bit, and tried to
> recover it thru Q&A, but, on starting with "Try Another Way,&...
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/1784956/how-do-i-recover-a-g-mail-account

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out the [tour] and [ask]. Request for help about recovering Google / Gmail account is better suited for https://support.google.com/accounts/community. Before posting, please review their guidance posts.